# django inplaceedit testing project

Tags: django, virtualenv, django-inplaceedit

New to django… Since a month i'm trying to follow [this](https://github.com/goinnn/django-inplaceedit-bootstrap/tree/master/testing) tutorial without success. When i syncdb i get following error:

```
(virt-inplaceedit)Mac:testing manuelstrasser$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 123, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sorl.thumbnail.fields import ImageField
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/fields.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sorl.thumbnail import default
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/default.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sorl.thumbnail.helpers import get_module_class
  File "/Users/manuelstrasser/Desktop/inplace/virt-inplaceedit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sorl/thumbnail/helpers.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.utils import simplejson
ImportError: cannot import name simplejson
```

I installed simplejson but still same error. Anyone haveing experiences with this tutorial? I did everything exactly as per description…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.utils.simplejson` is deprecated in django 1.7.

Looks like you use old version of the `sorl-thumbnail`.  [Current version](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail) of `sorl-thumbnail` supports django 1.7 so try to update this library.

Comment: thank u so much, everything working perfect with django 1.6 which is fine for tesing